# What is the correct syntax for specifying a trigger inside a UML State Machine action?

Tags: uml, state-machine

I am inside a submachine and I want to trigger a transition from the containing submachinestate to another state.  What's the correct notation for this?  That is,

Submachine:
Ready [Is_Conencted] / trigger Go -> terminate node

Machine:
Go / -> Running

What's the UML syntactically correct way to say "trigger Go"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In statecharts, like IAR visualSTATE, with Signals (in addition to Events), the syntax to fire a `Go` signal is

```
 Ready [Is_Conencted] / ^Go
```

Statecharts do not fire Events -- they come from external sources.

Comment: Yes, signals and events may each cause transitions. In visualSTATE, all pending signals are processed before the next event is dequeued.